# Trying to run a unittest module

Tags: python

I have created a unittest module called `test_blbmktdata.py` to test some code.  I am trying to run it from the console using the following command:

```
run test_blbmktdata.py
```

However I get the error message:

```
ERROR:root:File `'test_blbmktdata.py'` not found.
```

Please see below for the module code.

```
import unittest

class TestBlbMktData(unittest.TestCase):
    staticName='StaticInstrumentData.csv'


    def print(self,data):
        print()
        print(len(data))
        print(data.head())
        print(data.dtypes)

    def read(self,name,func):
        return func(os.path.join(self.current_dir,name))

    def setUp(self):
        self.current_dir=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    def test_corp_act(self):
        self.print(self.read(self.corpName,readCorpAction))
     
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    unittest.main()
```

How can I run the code from the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `python -m unittest test_blbmktdata` in terminal
https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface

Comment: Thanks, trying this gives me a SyntaxError: invalid syntax  :  python -m unittest test_blbmktdata

Comment: @Stacey run from the command line, not from inside the python interpreter

Comment: Sorry misunderstood, thanks.  That worked.  Just wondering, is there a way to run the code from inside the console?

Comment: Python is an interpreted language you can not run .py file within python console. You have to run it line by line within console.

Answer (score 0):

For running a python code say `code.py` you can simply use command

```
python code.py
```

on the terminal after you navigate to the same directory where code is located.